# ocaml not loading a .cma as expected

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to do the following

1. Work on a library spread out amongst a few ocaml modules
2. Compile the library
3. Load it into the REPL to experiment with the public API

In order to do 1 and 2, I am using [jbuilder](https://github.com/janestreet/jbuilder) together with an opam file. Now all of this works great for compiling my library easily, however I'm having trouble testing it in the repl.

My current approach is to spin up a repl and use `#load "_build/default/<name-of-main-library-module>.cma`. This executes successfully as I have already `#require`ed my dependencies. However, this doesn't actually seem to impact the set of bindings in the repl. Neither `MainLibraryModule` is bound as a module nor is the public API introduced unqualified by the module name.

Am I doing something obviously wrong here, how should I load this `cma` file so I can play around with my library. If there is an altogether better way to accomplish task 3 (without modifying global state in any way) I'm open to this as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use the modules defined in a `.cma` file, the REPL needs to be able to find the corresponding `.cmi` files, which are compiled interface files for the modules in your library.

This is the use case of the `#directory <path_to_cmis>;;` directive which adds the directory `<path_to_cmis>` to the list of directory potentially containing cmi files.

In your case, you need to add this directive `#directory` before the 
`#load` directive:

```
#directory "build/path_to_cmis";;
#load "build/path_to_cma";;
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `#load`, the top-level names of the loaded module are not introduced as top-level names of the REPL. To get this effect you need to `open` the module.

```
# #load "unix.cma";;
# stat;;
Error: Unbound value stat
# Unix.stat;;
- : string -> Unix.stats = <fun>
# open Unix;;
# stat;;
- : string -> Unix.stats = <fun>
```

How are you checking for the binding of a module name?